# Maximum edges for bipartite graph where all vertices of one part have degree 1

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, bipartite-graphs

I am looking for a method/algorithm to find the maximum edges possible for a bipartite graph where one part only has nodes of degree one.

I guess a good example would be an algorithm matching as many students as possible to a teacher for a given class. Teachers will teach many students, but each student only has one teacher.

I would also want to modify such an algorithm to include other constraints, like availabilities for example.

Additionally, is there a name for this specific type of bipartite graph?

Comment: You mean *degree* one, not "order" one.

Comment: My mistake, thanks

Comment: The algorithm is called maximum bipartite matching.

Comment: @SabaTavdgiridze From what I have read of maximum bipartite matching, it wouldn't apply since matchings are one to one. I want to consider relationships where vertices on one side have many edges, like teachers and students or representatives and their constituents.